# Javascript function works in all browsers except Edge

Tags: javascript, function

This function doesn't open links in a new window in Edge. Works in all other browsers. Not sure what the problem is:

```
function externalLinks() {
  for (var c = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), a = 0; a < c.length; a++) {
    var b = c[a];
    b.getAttribute("href") && b.hostname !== location.hostname &&
      (b.target = "_blank")
  }
};
externalLinks();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196225/discussion-on-question-by-jim-james-javascript-function-works-in-all-browsers-ex).

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
b.hostname !== location.hostname
```

to

```
(b.hostname || b.href.hostname) !== location.hostname
```

Modern browsers have the properties of the `href` in the anchor element. If it's not there, this will try to access it from the `href` property.

Comment: Made a mistake, it was supposed to be `b.hostname`

Comment: lol the link from `msdn.microsoft.com` that comes up if you google for "msdn anchor element" is a link to the MDN page.

Comment: In my Chrome 74 console, I did `var b = document.querySelector('a#mylink')` to get an anchor element. With that, `b.hostname` gave `somehost.example.com` while `b.href.hostname` produced `undefined` — so this may work for IE/Edge but it will still need a test to decide which method to use to get the hostname.

Comment: @Barmar Changing to `(b.hostname || b.href.hostname) !== location.hostname` prevents it from working in IE / Edge. `b.href.hostname` by itself works just fine.

Comment: But `b.href.hostname` won't work in other browsers. How about reversing it to `(b.href.hostname || b.hostname)`?

Comment: @Barmar Still doesn't work in IE / Edge. `b.href.hostname` on its own does work. It works in all browsers. Are you trying to put `b.hostname` back because you think it may not work in some browsers without it?

Comment: Yes, there's no `b.href.hostname` in other browsers

Comment: I don't know why this would work in IE. I just tried it in browserstack, since I'm on a Mac, and .href.hostname didn't work

Comment: @Pointy didn't msdn and mdn merge?

Comment: @FilipHaglund apparently, at least in effect, but there used to be a *lot* of content at MSDN. And there are plenty of `?` support marks for IE on MDN (if I recall).